# Can't get object key in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem:** I am making an app with Firebase and React Native where users can post, and then other users can comment on posts. To do the comments, I need to grab the key of the content of a post. I tried using the child.getKey() function, but that gave me an error.

```
child.getKey is not a function. (In 'child.getKey()', 'child.getKey' is undefined)
```

I would really love some help getting the key. Thank you!

**Code**

```
  getItems(){
    var items = [];
    var query = ref.orderByKey();
    query.once ('value', (snap) => {
      snap.forEach ( (child) => {       
       items.push({
         content: child.val().content,
         key: child.getKey()
     });
     });
    items.reverse();
    }).then(() => {
        this.setState({firebaseItems: items});
    });
 }
```

**Firebase layout**

```
Posts:
    -Kier498dma39md:
        content: 'This is an example post. The numbers above me are an example of the random key I am trying to get.'
```

Comment: What happens if you log snap and child? What are those? Objects? Functions?

Comment: I used FirebaseListAdapter. Inside the setOnItemClickListener of my listview I used firebaseListAdapter.getRef(i); to get the reference to the object(Where i is the position of the item in the list).